# Access Generated Excel Spreadsheet fails after multiple runs

Tags: excel, ms-access

I wrote a program in an Access form using VBA to take excel spreadsheets and load them to tables in an Access database. In addition to this I also wrote programs in Access to generate custom spreadsheets for analysis from those tables. There are several different reports that come in that need to be loaded to the database to different tables. This causes several different types of reports that need to be generated from the database to the different departments, depending on the data pertinent to that department. The program works flawlessly for me.

HOWEVER, One of my co-workers needs to be able to use the database to load data and generate the reports.

I actually wrote the programs for the other department. The Access database is maintained on our network.

My co-worker has exactly the same version of Access that I do. We have gone through the options on Access to ensure that both of our systems are set up in the same way (as it pertains to MS Access).

BUT... Every time he try's to run the report generator, the program presents an error. One of the error messages we receive is Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed.

This is only one of the messages we get back.

On the Load programs he can use the single load. (load a single file to a table) with no issue.

On the Load program that loads multiple files to a table, the program gets through two before erroring out.

The report generator builds multiple reports based on region. The program fails after generating a report for two regions.

I have looked at Access exhaustively. I have looked online. I can't find where the problem is coming from.

I can run ALL of the programs on my system with no issues. I have seen Access programs freak out when you are opening and closing file without enough of a pause. That isn't the issue. My system runs at 3.6GHZ while his runs at a more modest 2.8GHZ.

We are running the exact same version of Windows 10. We are running the same version of Access.

I am at a loss. Do you have any idea what the problem could be or do you have any suggestions as to where I might look for an answer.

The program fails in the middle of generating the Excel file after generating at least 2 with no problems.

Comment: You tagged Excel, but this is prior to Excel according to your narrative.

Comment: Yes, I tagged Excel first because I've done such exhaustive research into the problem with Access and VBA. The only rock I think the problem may be under is the way that Excel interacts with Access. I didn't know that there was an issue with the order of the tags. I didn't realize I was going to be critiqued on how I stated the problem instead of possibly being helped by the community.